# jquery toggle on multiple divs only working on first element

Tags: jquery

ive created a page but it's only toggling the first div and the other 2 arent working... can't work out why! Thanks in advance

```
var levelopen=false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.contentlevel').hide();
    $('#levelopener').click(function(){
        if(levelopen==false)
        {
            $('#levelopener').html('[less]'); 
            levelopen=true;
        }
        else
        {
            $('#levelopener').html('[more]');
            levelopen=false;
        }
        $(this).next(".contentlevel").slideToggle(100);
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q2qxX/4/

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have several elements with the same id (`levelopener`), ids must be unique. Use a class of `levelopener` and the selector `.levelopener` for the click event.

Also, use `$(this)` to refer to current item that's being clicked for the comparisons like you have for the toggling.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have multiple elements with the same id and you should use the `this` object when referring to the object calling the method.

http://jsfiddle.net/x8RW6/

```
var levelopen=false;
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.contentlevel').hide();
$('.levelopener').click(function(){
    if(levelopen==false)
        {
        $(this).html('[-]'); 
        levelopen=true;
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).html('[+]');
        levelopen=false;
    }
        $(this).next(".contentlevel").slideToggle(100);
        return false;
});
});
```

### [EDIT](http://jsfiddle.net/x8RW6/1/)

after some consideration, I've determined the function needs just a few other tweaks. :P

```
var levelopen=false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.contentlevel').hide();
    $('.levelopener').click(function(){
        if($(this).next(".contentlevel").is(":visible"))
            $(this).html('[+]'); 
        else
            $(this).html('[-]');

        $(this).next(".contentlevel").slideToggle(100);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: why return `false` and not `event.preventDefault()` ?

Comment: Thank you so much this works perfectly, I have just started learning jquery so now it seems such a stupid mistake! Cheers!

Comment: @Interstellar-Coder because that's part of the posters code that I didn't change. :P  Is there a particular advantage to using preventDefault?

Comment: @jkl9 no problem. :) glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

in your html , all your links have the same id -levelopener
HTML id's should be unique

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not correct IDs must be unique across all elements in a page.

Try this instead...Here is a modified fiddle using a common classname instead of id

http://jsfiddle.net/q2qxX/10/

Answer (score 0):

**`id`s must be unique** so your selector is only grabbing the first one.  Change your id to a class and use a class selector in your jQuery.

```
$('.levelopener').click(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have multiple `a` tags with the same id. Switch them to classes and it works perfectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/q2qxX/7/

Updated code based on comment to use `this` inside the click function.

Comment: the +/- toggle is broken... substitute `#levelopener` with `this`

Comment: Thanks :), too quick to answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can't have the same ID's in one html page.